# PHP get QUERY_STRING after '/'

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, pdo, query-string

I have my domain name and I would like to get the query from a URL like this: `http://domain.com/querystring`  and output would then be: `querystring`

It is the same technique bit.ly uses and Facebook for profile pages. Do I have to do something in my .htaccess file? or is there a normal PHP command to do so.. I think it would some kind of .htaccess URL rewriting, but I would just know if there is any other option.

Comment: See [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: I don't remember off my head, but there's a key in `$_SERVER` you can use for it. `print_r($_SERVER)` should tell you.

Comment: Look at this article:
http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Facebook example :
`www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=####`

then uses mod_rewrite to look like `www.facebook.com/username`

but to get the `username` the code is :

```
$_GET['id'];
```

Facebook has references to the `id` and `usernames` in its db tables

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?username=$1`
This is my .htaccess code.. I need to put in a dot `.` . how to do so? Does this works like normal Regex?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a web-server, like Apache and `index.php` is your controller.

Enable **mod_rewrite**, then config an `.htaccess` file in the root directory (or your vhost definition).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Then use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Check the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) superglobal.

Comment: Without mod_rewrite, PHP normally would not be triggered with only http://domain.com/querystring

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to use part of the URI for your query, you can get the entire URI from the $_SERVER superglobal like this, then break it apart to get whatever piece you might need

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pieces = explode("/", $uri);
$myQuery = $pieces[1];
```